# При сборке Java-FX приложения в jar файл перестают загружаться модальные окна

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Здравствуйте. Есть FX приложение (игра на подобии миллионера), в компиляторе (Intellij Idea) оно отлично работает, но после сборки в Jar-ник, и при открытии этого самого Jar-ника в нем работает только главное окно приложения, т.е. класс, который я указал как main class в меню сборки, но при нажатии каких либо клавиш в этом меню ничего не происходит, хотя должны начать прорисовываться модальные окна(новая игра, рекорды и т.д.), т.е. складывается такое впечатление, что в jar-файле хранится только main класс, и его fxml файл, а все остальные файлы проекта бесследно исчезли. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема, и как ее решить.

Comment: Вы откройте свой jar файл с помощью архиватора и посмотрите что внутри лежит.

Comment: открыл, все файлы на месте, но тем не менее почему то не используются jar-ником

Comment: когда делаете сборку проекта - все нужные файлы включаются в сборку?

Comment: да, всю папку с проектом